# How can we wait for a message text to pop up in selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this selenium application that contains an uploads file function that gets called recursively after every upload on the website

**Problem:**

The function is being called very quickly and it is not waiting for the upload to be done. Which is messing up the whole application process. I know I can add `time.sleep()` however I do not know the size of the files and how long the upload will take. So I prefer to add a check to see if the files are uploaded

**My Solution**

Luckily for me a successful message pops up when uploads are done

[image]

So I decided to add the `success_element` that waits for the success message to pop out as seen in the code below

```
def upload(driver, fileNum, filePath):
      #click ok to upload
      ok_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("borderButton")
      ok_link.click()
      #wait for success message to pop out( FAILS )
      success_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1200)
      success_element =   success_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.LINK_TEXT("File(s) have(s) been uploaded successfully!")))
      #call function again to upload more after succesful message pops out
      upload(driver, fileNum, filePath)
```

**Error**:

I got this error below right after the first group of files are uploaded, because it did not find the success message right away, which it is not supposed to anyway and I thought it would wait for it after upload is done for 1200 seconds (roughly 20 minutes which is the max)

How can I solve this problem. Any other solutions ?

> success_element =
>   success_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.LINK_TEXT("File(s)
>   have(s) been uploaded successfully!"))) TypeError: 'str' object is not
>   callable

Comment: you need to switch using driver.switch_to.window() to your pop-up

Comment: Probably not related to your question, but : Why do you make a recursive call to upload? Isn't it easier and lighter to create a loop ?

Comment: @BigOldTree I do not understand can you please expand ?

Comment: @BriceP the upload function includes a while loop, drop down element selection, before reaching the upload page, and I wanna repeat all these steps and thought that recursive function would be ideal

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure, but I think that using a recursion instead of a loop (even if it is nested into another one) won't unload the objects from one pass to the next one, as the main function is not finished until every other is. If you make a loop, I would say that the local variables used in the loop are deleted before the next loop runs. But as i said, I don't think it is related in any way to your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those whom had the same issue I found a solution, and it is using `EC.presence_of_element_located` instead. Which waits for the element to be located or throws an error after 20 minutes

```
success_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1800)
success_element = success_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "successmessage")))
```